# Гистограмма Excel при помощи С#

Tags: c#, excel

Создаю новый эксель файл в котором записывается результат выполнения программы. Для того, чтобы можно было отслеживать динамику изменения показателя. Но так же требуется сделать вывод этой динамики при помощи гистограммы, которая будет создаваться автоматически.

Сам код:

```
int[] counts = new int[64];

Excel NewExcelForResult = new Excel($"{WorkingDirectory}Result.xlsx", 0);
int Row = 1;
int i = 0;
while (excel.ReadCell(1, Row) != null)
{
    counts[i] = Convert.ToInt32(excel.ReadCell(1, Row));
    ++Row;
    ++i;
}
NewExcelForResult.WriteToCeil(0, Row, Result.ToString());
NewExcelForResult.Save();
```

//Тут надо построить график.
Прошу о помощи в создании данной гистограммы.

Comment: Вы хотя бы напишите, какого типа ваше приложение: WinForms, WPF, Xamarin или может быть веб?

Comment: Должно быть вам нужно [это](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/com/creating-excel-charts-in-c.html)